# Any way to do such a select

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Ok so here is my mysql Query

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CallCenterID) FROM tbl_mytable WHERE USER=1;
```

So this query gives me all those queries where `user=1`.Is there any way to get all  those `CallCenterID` which have `user!=1` and also `user=1` both using a single select query.

what i want is some thing like `GroupConcat(CallCenterIds_not_in_user=1),GroupConcat(CallCenterIds_in_user=1)`

Comment: Forgive me but you want to get those that =1 and those that !=1, is that not all of them?

Comment: drop where condition! :)

Comment: Show us your expected result and table structure please.

Comment: @F4r-20 i want to get both separate

Comment: So essentially you want to select everything? Exclude the where entirely. EDIT: You're going to need two selects if you want the data seperated.

Comment: @Chris.Ackley ys all but both divide based on the user category

Comment: `group by user order by user`?

Comment: Perhaps a little clarification to the question? Do you want two separate results, or just for those in which user=1 listed first? If the latter, the answers suggesting ORDER BY USER should work.

Comment: what i want is some thing like GroupConcat(CallCenterIds_not_in_user=1),GroupConcat(CallCenterIds_in_user=1)

Comment: Just check my answer from 10 minutes ago....

Comment: @jade: my answer includes several possible resultsets. I think one of them may be what you are looking for. Check the link to the SQL Fiddle  for a working demonstration of each query.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 SELECT USER=1, GROUP_CONCAT(CallCenterID) FROM tbl_mytable GROUP BY USER=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way to do such a select. The actual query really depends on the resultset you want returned. Do you want one row or two separate rows? Should CallCenterId ever be duplicated within a list?  Do you want CallCenterId excluded from the list for user!=1 if it appears in the list for user=1?  All of those are possible.

---

## [SQL Fiddle Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/540d7/5)

---

Test case:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_mytable( `user` INT UNSIGNED, CallCenterId VARCHAR(2));
INSERT INTO tbl_mytable 
 VALUES (1,'a'),(1,'b'),(2,'a'),(2,'c'),(2,'a'),(2,'d'),(NULL,'x');
```

---

One possible interpretation of the specification, is that you want a list of all CallCenterId for user=1, and you want another list of ALL CallCenterId that appear in the table but which do not appear the list for user=1. Basically, you want a CallCenterId to appear in one list or the other but NOT both. In the test case, this would mean you would want to return something like this:

```
user=1  NOT user=1  
------  ----------
a,b     c,d,x
```

That resultset can be returned by a query like this:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(IF(user_one,t.CallCenterId,NULL) 
       ORDER BY t.CallCenterId
       ) AS `user=1`
     , GROUP_CONCAT(IF(user_one,NULL,t.CallCenterId)
       ORDER BY t.CallCenterId
       ) AS `NOT user=1`
  FROM ( 
         SELECT u.CallCenterId
              , MAX(IF(u.user=1,1,0)) AS user_one
           FROM tbl_mytable u
          GROUP BY u.CallCenterId
       ) t
```

---

Another possible interpretation is that you want the two CallCenterID lists returned on the same row, with one list containing the CallCenterId for user=1, and the other list containing all CallCenterId for all users OTHER than user=1, meaning, the same CallCenterId can appear in both lists.  In that case, something like this will work:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IF(t.`user`=1,t.CallCenterID,NULL)
       ORDER BY t.CallCenterId
       ) AS `user=1`
     , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IF(t.`user`!=1,t.CallCenterID,NULL)
       ORDER BY t.CallCenterId
       ) AS `user!=1`
  FROM tbl_mytable t
```

returns:

```
user=1  user!=1  
------  ---------
a,b     a,c,d
```

---

It's also possible to return those lists as two separate rows, if that works better for you.

```
SELECT IF(t.`user`=1,'user=1','user!=1') AS `which_users`
     , GROUP_CONCAT(t.CallCenterID ORDER BY t.CallCenterId) AS `call_centers`
  FROM tbl_mytable t
 GROUP BY which_users
 ORDER BY which_users DESC
```

(NOTE: the call_centers list for 'user!=1' will also include values for rows where the `user` column is NULL; those rows can be excluded with a slight tweak.)

```
which_users  call_centers  
-----------  --------------
user=1       a,b           
user!=1      a,a,c,d,x
```

---

A slightly different query will eliminate duplicates in the list (using the DISTINCT keyword), and eliminating any rows where the `user` column IS NULL (adding a WHERE clause):

```
SELECT IF(t.`user`=1,'user=1','user!=1') AS `which_users`
     , GROUP_CONCAT(t.CallCenterID ORDER BY t.CallCenterId) AS `call_centers`
  FROM tbl_mytable t
 WHERE t.user IS NOT NULL 
 GROUP BY which_users
 ORDER BY which_users DESC
```

returns:

```
which_users  call_centers
-----------  ------------
user=1       a,b
user!=1      a,c,d
```

---

If none of these are what you are looking for, you'll need to specify more clearly what resultset you want returned.

Answer (score 0):

Im thinking you want all of them, so no condition:

```
SELECT USER, GROUP_CONCAT(CallCenterID) FROM tbl_mytable ORDER BY USER
```

This means that it won't even check the `user` column. The `ORDER BY` will group the records with similar `USER` values together.

Comment: i want all but want to know which one belongs to User =1 and which one not

Answer (score 0):

Hello try this out? Are you referring to something like this? You may replace `name` with `callerid` and `someid` with `userid`. The userid I have used is just the unique key for the table, it doesn't refer to the `userid` as per yours :)

[REference SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0912/2)

Query

```
select group_concat(name)
from mytable
where someid = 1
group by someid
;
```

Results:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(NAME)
tim,ron,kate,pete
```

- [**SQLFIDDLE REFERENCE for further queries**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0912/4)

Comment: @Jade click on the reference SQLfiddle link, you can see the results :)